# Full Cluster vs Load Balancing

Tags: load-balancing, .net, cluster

Is there any solutions that "increases power of a single machine" instead of traffic distribution between different hosts.

I mean the following schema:

"Central server" receives all requests and for its execution it provide "a copy of shared memory" to different hosts.

Thanks a lot.

P.S. I need that for .NET based web application.

Comment: Buy a bigger server?

Comment: I would say: buy an additional server(s). The question is: what is a good solution to make a cluster of web servers (not a web farm, but a cluster) that not balance load, but perform execution in the "same process" (which doesn't require thinking about such things like keep unique cache storage, keep unique session data storage, different machines synchronization, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a Microsoft Compute Cluster.  Not sure if you can run an ASP.NET app on it.  It's available on TechNet and MSDN if you have a subscription to either.  Look for "Compute Cluster Pack".  There is info available on microsoft.com as well.

I'm curious why the need for the large single cluster system instead of using a more traditional load balanced web farm?

Comment: 1st of all I would like to see if there are any option (except of load balancing web farm). Why? .. You know, you never know... :) Thanks P.S. CCP is designed for C, C++, and .NET developers and those writing scripts.

Comment: OK, fare enough.  I can understand research for researches sake.

Comment: Not only researches sake... we are thinking about 'web farm', and I'm trying to figure out if there are any other options

Comment: CCP - is a good option as far as I see. Thanks. But any other ideas are welcome also!

Comment: After better reading found that CPP doesn't use shared memory... but I think that is really not possible with current technologies yet...

Comment: Sharing memory between servers would require a massive amount of very fast bandwidth between the machines.  I don't know if 10Gig would have a low enough latency to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but memcached ( http://memcached.org/ ) does shared caching (in RAM) across clusters.

Extensively used on *nix systems, not sure how well it's supported for Windows applications, but happily there is a thread on that exact subject over on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351635/memcached-with-windows-and-net

Comment: Thanks. I am aware about memcached, but I don't need cache engine. What I do need is a architectural/engineering solution that allows for building cluster (not web farm that is based on Load Balancing).